# Union of Upper Limit Topology and Lower Limit Topology is Discrete Topology

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

The basis for upper and lower limit topology is $\lbrace (a,b]\mid a<b\rbrace$ and $\lbrace [a,b)\mid a<b\rbrace$ respectively. But the basis of discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is $\lbrace\lbrace x\rbrace\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace$. How can I show that they are the same? I can not find a similar question to this and I have no ideas how to show this. Any hints would be most appreciated.

Comment: In general, union of two topology is not a topology.

Comment: But this time it is. Isn't it?

Comment: No, the union only forms a subbase for a new topology and that topology is the discrete one. Otherwise put: the only topology on $\Bbb R$ that is finer than both the upper and the lower topology is the discrete one. It's easy to show.

Comment: But how to show that NO other topology is finer than both upper and lower limit topologies?

Comment: Useful observation: For every $a$, and every $\epsilon > 0$, both $(a-\epsilon, a]$ and $[a, a+ \epsilon)$ are in the union.

Comment: The intersection of these two topologies is the Euclidean topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all intervals of the form $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$ are open, then for any $x\in \Bbb R$, we have that $$\{x\}=(x-1,\,x]\,\cap\, [x,\,x+1)$$
is open.